# Pyvmomi get folders name

Tags: python, django, vsphere, pyvmomi

I'm new to Python and Django and I need to list all my VMs.
I used pyvmomi and Django but I can't get the folders name from VSphere, it shows a strange line.

> VMware list
>
> 'vim.Folder:group-v207'
>
> 'vim.Folder:group-v3177'
>
> 'vim.Folder:group-v188'

I have 3 folders on vSphere so I think my connection it's good but that's absolutely not their names.

Here is my code :

views.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
from django.shortcuts import render
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect, Disconnect
import ssl

def home(request):
    s = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    s.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    try:
        connect = SmartConnect(...)
    except:
        connect = SmartConnect(...)
    datacenter = connect.content.rootFolder.childEntity[0]
    vmsFolders = datacenter.vmFolder.childEntity
    Disconnect(connect)
    return render(request, 'vmware/home.html', {'vmsFolders':vmsFolders})
```

home.html

```
<h1>VMware list</h1>
{% for vmFolder in vmsFolders %}
<div>
    <h3>{{ vmFolder }}</h3>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Can anybody help me to get the real names of my folders?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specifically state you want the name, like this:

```
vmFolders = datacenter.vmFolder.childEntity
for folder in vmFolders:
    print(folder.name)
```